# Swift: iOS 15 date formatter to convert date to a custom string

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert a date to a string using iOS 15 style formatter like this:

```
let date = Date()
let formattedDate = date.formatted(
            .dateTime
            .month(.twoDigits)
            .day()
            .year()
)
```

The Date (as printed in the console) is

```
"2022-06-19 16:42:56 +0000"
```

How can I build the following string:

```
"2022 ** 06 ** 19"
```

out of this date object, using the new iOS 15 date formatter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to construct a *verbatim format style,* such as this:

```
    let date = Date()
    let formatString : Date.FormatString = """
        \(year: .defaultDigits) ** \
        \(month: .twoDigits) ** \
        \(day: .twoDigits)
        """
    let format = Date.VerbatimFormatStyle(
        format: formatString,
        locale: .autoupdatingCurrent,
        timeZone: .autoupdatingCurrent,
        calendar: .init(identifier:.gregorian)
    )
    let s = date.formatted(format) // 2022 ** 06 ** 19
```